# Best way to transfer Wordpress install to root of directory when I'm ready to launch?

Tags: directory

I'm currently designing a site for a client and I don't want anyone to be able to navigate to the homepage and see it. So currently the site is located in a subfolder of the main domain. Like so: http://gointrigue.com/beta/

What steps do I need to take to move the site to simply http://gointrigue.com/ when we are ready to launch it?

Or, is there a way to move it there right now, while I'm still developing it, and simply hide the homepage from the outside world while I can still see it? The only reason I decided to develop it in a subfolder like /beta/ was because I didn't know how to stop other people from seeing the homepage while still allowing myself to see it.

What's the easiest, simplest answer here? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Moving WordPress « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress), or, keep all WP files (except index.php) in /beta/ and see [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory « WordPress Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory)

Use [WordPress › Absolute Privacy « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/absolute-privacy/) to make WP private until launch.